# Finding repeat call

Tags: mysql

I want find out the repeat calls from as like below data table. Any call
count as a repeat when some one call one more time for same issue(Call_Outcome).

```
UCID    Phone_Number    Call_Time   Call_Outcome    Call_ID Skill_Name
121312  01819202020      11:11  Balance              1231   Corporate
121310  01819202020      11:11  Call drop            1231   Corporate
413921  01819202020      01:21  balance              3212   corporate
213412  01819202020      01:32  Call drop            2312   corporate
213412  01819202020      01:32  Goon goon            2312   corporate
987654  01823898989      04:12  Gprs                 2345   IR
434323  01823898989      05:12  Gprs                 2131   IR
213143  01819202020      06:23  Goon                 5676   corporate
213143  01819202020      06:23  balance              5676   corporate
```

The Result should be like that as belows

```
SkillName   Ans Repeat
Cor          4   3
IR           2   1
```

I tried with following query but it doesn't give the exact result.

```
select left(Skill_Name,3)as SkillName, count(call_Id) as Ans, 
count(UCID) as RepeatCall 
from(select UCID, Phone_Number, Skill_Name, Call_Outcome,     count(Call_Outcome)-1 as cqc 
from cdr where UCID IN (SELECT A.UCID FROM cdr A INNER JOIN (SELECT Phone_Number, Call_Outcome
 FROM cdr GROUP BY Phone_Number, Call_Outcome HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) B ON   A.Phone_Number = B.Phone_Number AND A.Call_Outcome = B.Call_Outcome 
ORDER BY `A`.`Phone_Number`) 
group by Phone_Number, Call_Outcome)As rep
 where cqc<>0 group by SkillName;
```

Comment: "Call_ID" needs to be added to the first nested select statement.

Comment: Yah, you r right. but there is another problem with time , here I have to use minimum Call_time for the exact repeat call number . But I can't use this condition accurately #WorkSmarter